# Error while trying to connect to VDI using Citrix Receiver in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, citrix, vdi

I am trying to connect to VDI using citrix receiver. I'am successfully logged in but while I am clicking on the VDI icon, I'm getting below error -

[image]

This is working fine in windows but not in Ubuntu.

Below is some more info which might help -

```
OS                      : Ubuntu
Release                 : 16.04 LTS
Citrix Receiver Version : 13.5 for Linux
```

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score -1):

upgrade the citrix receiver  verion and try

seems issue with receiver. ICA protocol not let communicate